# NgTable with Angular 2/4

Tags: angular, ngtable

I tried to make a table ussing ngTable for Angular 2/4 .. But I got an error when running App ..
My Ts File :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgTableParams } from 'ng-table';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-folders',
  templateUrl: './folders.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./folders.component.css']
})
export class FoldersComponent implements OnInit {
  folders: any = {};
  result: any = [];
  tableParamsFolders = {};
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.foldersService.getAllFolders().subscribe(
      result => {
        this.result = result;
        this.tableParamsFolders = new NgTableParams({count : 10, page : 1}, {dataset: this.result});
      });
  }
}
```

And in my html component, I tried this :

```
 <div class="row">
          Show  1 to {{tableParamsFolders.settings().total}} on {{tableParamsFolders.settings().total}}
            <table ng-table="tableParamsFolders" show-filter="false">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="sortable col-md-2 sort-desc">
                        <div class="sort-indicator">N°</div>
                    </th>
                    <th class="sortable col-md-1">
                        <div class="sort-indicator">Type</div>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="clickable">
                    <tr *ngFor="let frnd of result">
                        <td data-title="'No'" filter="{ 'no': 'text' }" sortable="no">
                        {{frnd.ID}}
                         </td>
                        <td data-title="'Type'" filter="{ 'type': 'text' }" sortable="type">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
```

I got error like attachment file ..
And the pagination is not showed ..
If someone have an issue or a link for using ngTable in Angular 2/4
[image]

Comment: You could add `*ngIf="tableParamsFolders?.settings"` on outer div.. because angular is trying to call `settings` method on `tableParamsFolders` variable before it has `settings` function available in it

Comment: Yes thx .. no error now..But I don't undertand because for start I do `tableParamsFolders = new NgTableParams(); ` and in  NgTableParams we have this function .. an other question why the pagination is not show with ng-table for angular 2/4